# Is "technisch gesehen" an anglicism?

Tags: anglicism

As the title says, is the phrase *technisch gesehen* an anglicism? I'm wondering because, for one, I don't remember this being used so much in the past and, for another, I always think of techniques or mechanical or electronic stuff if the word *technisch* comes up.

In an example in [an article of Tagesanzeiger](http://www.tagesanzeiger.ch/wirtschaft/konjunktur/Das-ist-technisch-gesehen-schon-eine-Rezession/story/19881957), some guy responsible for finances talks about something being "technisch gesehen eine Rezession". He uses *technisch gesehen* in the form of *technically*, but of course a recession has nothing to do with technological matters.

Comment: Why should it be an anglicism? Could you give a context why you think so?

Comment: @IQV: I suppose this refers to the way "Technically, ..." is used in English in the sense of "Im Prinzip ..." or "Streng genommen ...". I agree that meaning of "technisch" is not usual in German, but then, I have not encountered any examples of *technisch gesehen* in German and thus have neither any concrete examples nor any references to discuss.

Comment: Run a Google n-grams search for "technisch gesehen" in German and for "technically" in English, and see how the usage varied over time?

Comment: In English-spoken countries, everyone can *technically agree* in a discussion. In German, only engineers are able to do that. So, your question can only be answered with more context.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question. I would speculate that the greek term "techne" (art, technique) is an older source of the meaning "die methodischen, verfahrensmäßigen, organisatorischen Äußerlichkeiten eines Vorgangs, einer Tätigkeit betreffend" (https://www.dwds.de/wb/technisch 2) of "technisch", but I tend to believe that the english influence is strengthening this meaning in german again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than German, English strictly distinguishes between *technique* and *technology*. In German, both resolve to "Technik", while the former meaning is, in a lot of uses, probably better translated as "Methode". This obviously has some influence on derived adverbs and adjectives.

*technically* is the English adverb for both *technique* and *technology*, while *technisch* is the adverb/adjective mainly for the *technology* part of the meaning of *Technik*.

Still, there are uses of *-technisch* outside the technology area in German  that relate more to the "Methode" meaning of *technisch*:

> Versicherungstechnisch gesehen ist das Problem lösbar
>
> Die lerntechnische Kompetenz der Schüler ist beeindruckend

My comment above on the standing expression "to technically agree on sth" relates to the "Methode" usage in German. A direct translation to German "technisch einer Meinung sein" would however be commonly understood as "to agree on technical matters" rather than "to agree in principle". This applies to your example "technisch gesehen" as well (but, admittedly, a bit softer than in my example - "from a technical viewpoint" already in English refers more to technology than technique and is not so much a standing expression as my example)

So, in case the expression would be used outside of a technology area, I would agree (and, at least partially) assume it is an (soft, because *technically speaking* (sic!) not wrong) anglicism or a literal translation into a rather uncommon usage.

Comment: What about "technisches Foul"?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach That's an anglicism in any case - but more because of *Foul* than because of *technisch*. At the same time, another example of *technisch* outside technology.

Comment: "Foul" ist ein englisches Wort, keine Frage. Aber das macht nicht direkt die Phrase "technisches Foul" einen Anglizismus. Bei Phrasen geht's nicht darum, ob ein bestimmter Bestandteil (also Wort) eingedeutscht wurde, sondern ob die Phrase an sich englischsprachige Grundlage hat. Sonst wäre "Das macht Sinn" kein Anglizismus, weil es auf Wortebene rein Deutsch ist.

Comment: I didn't mention "technisches Foul" becaus "foul" is an english word, but because the meaning of "technisch" in "technisches Foul" is the same as in "technisch gesehen" - so I tried to shed some light to your hypothesis. Does somebody when the phrase "technisches Foul" occurs in german? Maybe that might help answering the question.

Comment: 'In German, both resolve to "Technik"' - well, *Technologie* is often another possibility, but the crucial difference is indeed that in many contexts, *Technik* and words derived from it can (and will readily) be understood as being related to technology in German.

Comment: @Em1 Der Begriff "Anglizismus" bezeichnet alles, was wir aus der englischen Sprache übernehmen. Vollkommen egal, ob wir Wendungen wörtlich übersetzen oder den englischen Begriff übernehmen oder das Wort übernehmen und ihm eine neue Bedeutung verpassen ("Handy"). Daher ist "Foul" natürlich für sich alleine gesehen ein Anglizismus.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Ein *technisches Foul* dürfte mit großer Sicherheit auf ohne Beachtung des Begriffs *Foul* ein Anglizismus sein - Es kommt m.W. nur im Basketball vor und Basketball an sich ist ja schon ein sportlicher Anglizismus. Aber das "technische Foul" heißt in den amerikanischen Basketballregeln tatsächlich "technical foul". Und es bedeutet einen Fehler in der *Methodik* - Technologie kommt in dem Spiel ja vorrangig nicht vor.

Comment: @tofro Das wußte ich nicht. Es scheint mir also ein Indiz für die These zu sein, dass "technisch" in dieser Verwendung ein Anglizismus ist - zumindest ein Beispiel.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Nochmal gesucht: Die einzige "Sportart", die ich außer Basketball finden konnte, die ein "technisches Foul" kennt, scheint **Tischfußball** zu sein. Dort scheint man allerdings *alle* Regelverstöße als technisches Foul zu werten - Und es ist, da eine "Maschine" im Spiel ist, schwer zu sagen, ob es dabei um "Technologie" oder "Methode" geht.

Answer (score -4):

### No.

None of the words are English, so why should »*technisch gesehen*« be an anglicism?

An **anglicism** is an English word (or phrase) used in German. So it is strictly mandatory to have English words. If you use words from other languages, it never can be an anglicism.

---

### technisch

This adjective is derived from the noun **Technik**. Both words (»Technik« and »technisch«) began to be used in German language in the 18<sup>th</sup> century. The German words was derived from the Neolatin noun »*technica*« and the Neolatin adjective »*technicus*«, which already was in use as foreign words in German language in the 17<sup>th</sup> century.

Those Neolatin words meant: "art, science, artificial, scientific", and they have an ancient greek root: τεχνικός (*technikos*) which means: »skilled, professional, artfull, expertly, ...«

On its way from its ancient greek root to modern German the adjective »technisch« never touched English language.

---

### gesehen

This word is Partizip II of **sehen**, and this is a very old inherited word that always was German and can be traced back to Proto-Indo-Germanic roots.

Comment: "Das macht Sinn" is an anglicism (pointed out on [this site in german](http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/sprache/sinn-machen.php) ). Which of those three words is english?

Comment: -1 since the justification - "An anglicism is an English word (or phrase) used in German." of your answer is wrong. Anglicisms can also occur in grammatical or stylistic phenomena. Language is not only vocabulary.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Eine inhaltsleere Aussage, bedeutet doch Grammatik nichts anderes als Sprachwissenschaftlich. Worin soll denn sprachtechnisch gesehen der Stilunterschied von Englisch und Deutsch liegen, der das Reden von einem Anglizismus rechtfertigt? M.E. stimmt es zwar, dass englische Wendungen wie "Sinn machen" auch als Anglizismus bezeichnet werden - das steht hier jedoch nicht zur Debatte, da das *gesehen* in der Frage sogleich unter den Tisch fällt. M.E. lässt sich die Angliizismusvermutung nur empirisch nachweisen.